# AngularJS - Using .Then Instead of .Success is not working with HTTP function

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I've been searching a lot about the topic but couldn't find a solution still. I believe I am not handling the promise properly. I have a AngularJS MVC model working fine when I handle my API call with the .success but when I changed to .then ( because the other is depreciated ) it doesn't work. I can see in my http-server log that with the code below I still get the json file and I am using a simple json file for testing so I believe I did not forgot to define the view properly (like this [AngularJS - Can't access retrieved JSON data in the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22260031/angularjs-cant-access-retrieved-json-data-in-the-view) )

I also tested with the complete http.get syntax in the controller only but its also not working.

services.js

```
 angular.module('myApp.services', [])
 .factory('APIservice', function($http, $q) {

    var myAPIs = {};

    myAPIs.getFullList = function() {
        return $http.get("myFile.json", {timeout: 30000, cache:false});
    };

    //(...) more APIs here

    return myAPIs;
});
```

controllers.js

```
  angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
  .controller("Tablectrl", function($scope, $http, $q, APIservice) {

    var promise = APIservice.getFullList();
        promise.then(
            function(response) {
                $scope.myTable = response.records;
            },
            function(reason) { console.log('Error: ' + reason); }
        );
```

view

```
<div ng-controller="Tablectrl">
        <table border="0" style="width:100%" class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>ID &nbsp</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="myTable in myTable>
                <td>{{myTable.id}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
```

My JSON

```
  {  "records" : [
{
  "id" : "500006",
  (...)
},
 (...)
]
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: `response.data.records`

Comment: wow! Always a small detail to change everything! Thanks.

Comment: Yes Indeed defintely!